# Ubuntu Server stucks on high traffic

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-10.04

There are some servers on Ubuntu Server 10.04 with that particular hardware: [output of hwinfo](http://pastebin.com/csj1Wz1F).

The problem is the hangup when machine experiences a traffic higher than 10Mb/sec for several minutes; only hardware reset can bring the machine back to life.

Before the hangup occures, dmesg displays a repeated message like that:

```
[106142.897269] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link up
[106142.897280] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
[106146.198770] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link up
[106146.198782] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
[106146.537895] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link up
[106146.537907] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
[106147.525354] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link up
[106147.525365] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
```

But, of course, the PHY is always connected.

Are there any known ways how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [this kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32962).

You can either downgrade your kernel to one that didn't exhibit the problem, or upgrade to one in which it is fixed (3.4+).